# Teradata SQL - understanding performance impacts of inserting query results to a Volatile table

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a base query that extracts Record_ID + associated Service_Number, followed by a LEFT JOIN to look up an additional related Service_Code. I've confirmed there are unique records in each sub-table.

The explain plan shows total estimated time for this query as "1 min 25 seconds", yet if I wrap a CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE statement over the query, suddenly the explain plan shows total estimated time of "72 hours 20 minutes". If I run the VOLATILE TABLE creation anyway, the job finishes within the minute.

What contributes to this additional load time? Is there anything I can look at to reduce this?

Comment: I would guess MULTISET & lack of primary index eliminating the skew would add time substantially

Comment: Multiset actually makes it faster since it doesn't have to check for duplicates.  However, I think you are right about the primary index.

Comment: Interestingly whatever Primary Index I define, even NO PRIMARY INDEX, displays a massive increase in estimated time. This becomes a problem as the DBA has defined maximum 'estimated time' limits before Teradata will not allow my query to be executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estimated time isn't really an estimate of how long it will take to run.  They should really refer to it as "estimated cost" since it doesn't really indicate a remotely realistic estimate of the actual runtime.

Without seeing your actual script, my guess would be that you picked a bad primary index for your volatile table.  Since Teradata is massively parallel, it distributes your data between the AMPs based on the primary index.  If you pick a bad primary index then your data does not get evenly distributed and it may be trying to load all the data into a single AMP (in the worst case).  This can result in massive slowness.

If you just want to load data quickly without worrying about downstream performance then specify `NO PRIMARY INDEX` for your table and it will ensure an even distribution of data accross all AMPs.  However, this may give you less than great performance later on when you try to join this to other tables.  So it is a good idea to put some thought into your primary index.

Comment: Actually, if you keep in mind that we are talking about a cost estimate (and not actual time), 1 minute and 25 seconds isn't a horrible estimate.  Picking a good primary index might not make much difference if you are already seeing a pretty quick creation time.  Table drop and creation does take a little longer in massively parallel database platforms than some other database platforms

Comment: Thanks. As I just added in the comments of my original question, whatever  Primary Index I define, even NO PRIMARY index, displays a massive increase in estimated time in the explain plan. This becomes a problem as the DBA has defined maximum limits to the estimated time before I am unable to submit my query for execution

Comment: Oh, however possibly the second table I'm joining to has a poor primary index defined which is causing the skew? I'll check this out

Comment: Yes, the problem appears to have come from the underlying primary index in the table I was performing the LEFT JOIN on. I tested this by creating a new VOLATILE TABLE from this table defining the appropriate Primary Index, and now the 'estimated time' has reduced from 72 hours to 17 minutes.